# Create dictionary from pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a pandas dataframe with data as such:

[pandas dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRT7S.png)

From this I need to create a dictionary where Key is Customer_ID  and value is array of tuples(feat_id, feat_value).

Am getting close using to_dict() function on dataframe.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a comprehension:

```
out = {customer: [tuple(l) for l in subdf.to_dict('split')['data']]
        for customer, subdf in df.groupby('Customer_ID')[['Feat_ID', 'Feat_value']]}
print(out)

# Output
{80: [(123, 0), (124, 0), (125, 0), (126, 0), (127, 0)]}
```

Input dataframe:

```
>>> df
   Customer_ID  Feat_ID  Feat_value
0           80      123           0
1           80      124           0
2           80      125           0
3           80      126           0
4           80      127           0
```

Comment: though it gives TypeError: 'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

Answer (score 2):

you should first set `Customer_ID` as the DataFrame index and use `df.to_dict` with `orient='index'` to obtain a dict in the form {index -> {column -> value}}. (see [Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html?highlight=to_dict#pandas.DataFrame.to_dict)). Then you can extract the values of the inner dictionaries using dict comprehension to obtain the tuples.

```
df_dict = {key: tuple(value.values()) 
           for key, value in df.set_index('Customer_ID').to_dict('index').items()}
```